# Can I make fun of VW car company in a game?

Tags: european-union, trademark, parody

I'd like to make fun of a company in a computer game (obvious parody/satire/etc.). Let's say I change the logo, so it's a "WV" in a rectangle instead of a "VW" in a circle and change the companies chief executives name from "Matthias Müller" to "Matty Mule R.", is this legal or not in a computer game? Also, what are the boundaries (how far can I go) and what should I keep in mind to avoid doing something illegal?

Comment: Where are you located? Some locations have different laws on this sort of thing, and some specifically mention it is allowed.

Comment: @Terry In the EU, but the game would sell globally via the Steam platform if all goes as planned, which would naturally include the US as well.

Comment: In the US, you could probably even use the VW name and logo, and maybe even Matthias Muller's name and likeness, in your own for-profit game as long as you were clearly parodying them. I know little about how it would work in Europe other than being vaguely aware that speech/expression is generally more restricted there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about copyright, you can use the real VW logo if you're including it as a parody. (If you ever watch Family Guy, they do this all the time)

Comment: Is this true in Europe as well, though? Seems like a lot of things that hurt feelings are illegal there.

Comment: @Patrick87 I can remember a Simpsons episode which was on TV in Germany. They go to "blocko land" instead of "lego land". Then Lisa says something about Lego and Homer asks "Hey what do you mean?". So they really said the word Lego in the episode.

Comment: Yes, lot of things that hurt feelings are illegal in the EU. But in the EU, companies do not have feelings, so you can be quite rough with a company. We take care that it does not hurt the people too much even if you kill the company.